# setting up proxy with use of sftp in sublime text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

I am using Sublime Text 2 and the SFTP package.

Unfortunately, at work, they use a firewall that blocks a specific port thats required to upload files.  Were working on getting that port opened, but for now, i'd like to go through our companies proxy that will allow me to continue using sublime for the time being.

I've gone to `Preferences > Package Settings > Package Control > Settings – Default` and added my proxy information, but it doesnt seem to work.

Is there anything I need to do to get it working with SFTP?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sublime Text 3 sftp plugin proxy setting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25568369/sublime-text-3-sftp-plugin-proxy-setting)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, add your proxy setting like:

"http_proxy": "proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080",
"https_proxy": "proxy.iiit.ac.in:8080"

in Preferences > Package Settings > Package Control > **Settings – User**

And restart it!

If it did not work, try following steps:

1. open your Internet Explorer
2. tools →internet options→ advanced tag→ Security → Cancel "Check for Server Certificate revocation"
   this checkbox
3. Restart your Sublime Text and it work!

Hope it can help you.