# Sublime Text 3 sftp plugin proxy setting

Tags: windows, proxy, sftp, sublimetext3

I've installed sftp plugin for Sublime Text 3.

Is it possible to configure sftp with proxy?

I am looking for any proxy settings.

Does anyone know about this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `ProxyCommand` inside `sftp_flags`.

Something like this worked for me:

```
// Destination server info
"host": "dest.example.com",
"user": "foo",

// Proxy server info
"sftp_flags": [
    "-o",
    "ProxyCommand ssh foo@proxy.example.com -i ~/.ssh/bar.pem -W %h:%p"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your "Package Control.sublime-settings":

"http_proxy": "proxy.my.net:8080",
"https_proxy": "proxy.my.net:8080",

If it didn't work, try to use following steps:

1. open your Internet Explorer
2. tools →internet options→ advanced tag→ Security → Cancel "Check for Server Certificate revocation"
   this checkbox
3. Restart your Sublime Text and it work!

Hope it can help you.