# Sublime Text SFTP plugin with proxy port setting

Tags: proxy, port, sftp, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I'm using Sublime text 3. SFTP plugin is installed with package manager but it fails to find the host as my computer is behind a proxy server.

Assume my proxy server is 192.168.0.2 and it's running on port 6588.

Now how to tell SFTP plugin to make all connection using this proxy server.

### Error : Host could not found.

It will be really helpful to me and lot of peoples if someone suggests the solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sublime Text 3 sftp plugin proxy setting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25568369/sublime-text-3-sftp-plugin-proxy-setting)

Answer (score 0):

Open Preferences > Package Settings > Package Control > Settings – default

Ctrl+f Find "http_proxy"

add your proxy setting like:

"http_proxy": "your.proxy:port", "https_proxy": "your.proxy:port"

And restart it.

if it doesn't work, try to add above at:

Preferences > Package Settings > Package Control > Settings – User

If it still did not work, try following steps:

1. open your Internet Explorer
2. tools →internet options→ advanced tag→ Security → Cancel "Check for Server Certificate revocation"
   this checkbox
3. Restart your Sublime Text.

Hope it can help you.